# Duvida update php

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldade em alterar o estado do `user(1 -> ativo, 0-> desativo)`. Aparece-me a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\paw_EpN_G44\Application\Database\MyDataAccessPDOBase.php:161 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\paw_EpN_G44\Application\Database\MyDataAccessPDOBase.php(161): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\paw_EpN_G44\Application\Database\MyDataAccessPDO.php(155): MyDataAcessPDOBase->prepareStatement('UPDATE user SET...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\paw_EpN_G44\Application\Manager\UserManager.php(103): MyDataAccessPDO->update('user', Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\paw_EpN_G44\AreaAdmin\alterarEstado.php(29): UserManager->update_estado('gui ', '0') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\paw_EpN_G44\Application\Database\MyDataAccessPDOBase.php on line 161

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$userManager = new UserManager();

$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$myclient = $userManager->getUserByUsername($username);
$novoestado = $myclient['estado'];


if ($myclient['estado'] === "1") {
    $novoestado = "0" ;
} else {
  $novoestado = "1" ;
}

$userManager->update_estado($username, $novoestado);
```

Em que o `update_estado` é:

```
public function update_estado($user, $estado) {
        try {
            return $this->update(self::SQL_TABLE_NAME, 
                    Array('estado' => $estado),Array('username' => $user));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Margarida tenta melhorar o título da sua dúvida, vai ajudar aos outros a entender melhor e possilvemente lhe ajudar de uma forma mais apropriada e rápida.

Comment: A sua consulta SQL parece estar errada. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicioná-la? Pelo erro, ela está em `MyDataAccessPDO.php`, linha 155.